# Auto build maven project from a private bitbucket repo and jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, bitbucket

I've been working on auto-building a maven project with Jenkins.
Manually, from "start build" in Jenkins, it's working correctly, but from a bitbucket webhook :
"jenkins_url/bitbucket-hook/", after committing and pushing in my bitbucket repo, I'm getting in Jenkins's Bitbucket Hook Log this error :

```
FATAL: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote -h -- https://my_username@bitbucket.org/repo.git/" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/repo.git/'

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote -h -- https://my_username@bitbucket.org/repo.git/" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/repo.git/'
```

I'm using username and password credentials.

Wish you could help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution to my own question, if someone needs it.

Just use ssh access key to connect to your bitbucket repo (not username-password credentials) :

--> connect to jenkins user by `su jenkins` or `su -s /bin/bash jenkins`

--> generate your ssh key under `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh` by `ssh-keygen`

--> copy your private key in a jenkins global identifier

--> copy your public key in a bitbucket access key 
    and the build will work in both cases : manually and after a push to your 
    repository

(You will also need ssh publisher plugin in jenkins to put the bitbucket host id).